# What value of c makes this true?

Tags: limits, factorial

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(x)!}{x^{x}} = 0$

and

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(2x)!}{x^{x}} = \infty$

Is there a value c (or range of values) where

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(cx)!}{x^{x}} = 1$ ?

Comment: Any conjecture? Have you tried, say, [Wolfram Alpha with different $c$'s](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bx+%5Crightarrow+%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B(1.000001x)!%7D%7Bx%5E%7Bx%7D%7D)?

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is not _exactly_ what you're looking for, but it is close: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n}=1$$

Comment: Amazingly there is, try $c=1.00000000000001$ in @QuinnCulver 's link

Comment: @Nikunj that is probably a rounding thing.

Comment: @Prospect I see, it must have took it as 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Stirling, $$\frac{(cx)!}{x^x}\approx \frac{(cx)^{cx}e^{-cx}\sqrt{2\pi cx}}{x^x}=\left(\frac{c^cx^{c-1}}{e^c}\right)^{x}\sqrt{2\pi cx}$$
If $c=1$, this becomes $e^{-x}\sqrt{2\pi x}\to 0$, and if $c>1$ then $\frac{c^cx^{c-1}}{e^c}>1$ for $x\gg 0$ and hence $\left(\frac{c^cx^{c-1}}{e^c}\right)^{x}\sqrt{2\pi cx}$ grows faster tan $\sqrt{2\pi cx}\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

No. The reason any number greater than 1 results in it approaching infinity is that as x approaches infinity, any constant in front of it greater than 1 will be multiplied by itself an infinite number of times. So any number greater than 1 will result in infinity.